# PDF Creation script working with manual run, not in OnEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I've been building a timekeeping sheet for my company. In the interest of keeping things simple for the folks in the field I'm trying to get a script for creating a pdf of the timesheet to run off of a checkbox in the sheet.

I've got the function to actually create the PDF (createPDF) working when I run it manually, but when I try to trigger it off of an onEdit statement that monitors a particular checkbox in the sheet it doesn't work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() ;
  var shtn=s.getName();
  if(shtn=="Time sheet") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

    r = s.getActiveCell() ;
    var PDFTitle = s.getRange( 'V8' ).getValue() ;
    var EMAIL_RECIP = s.getRange( 'V6' ).getValue() ; 
    var EMAIL_BODY = 'Hello!\rPlease see the attached PDF document.';
    var OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "Submitted Timesheets" ;
    var APP_TITLE = "Timesheets Field" ;
    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var linecol = r.getColumn() ;
    var linerow = r.getRow() ;
    var rowsbetweentables = ( 19 ) ;
    var linerow2 = ( linerow - rowsbetweentables) ;
    var linerow3 = ( linerow2 + 9 ) ;
    var checkboxvalue = s.getRange( linerow , 2 ).getValue() ; 
    var commandstring = s.getRange( linerow , 1 ).getValue() ;
    var employeetablecount = 60 ;
    //Browser.msgBox(linecol);

    if((linecol == 2) && checkboxvalue == true && commandstring == "Email Timesheet") {
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(10000); // Using to offset any potential latency in creating .pdf
      s.getRange( 'B' + linerow ).setValue( false ) ; 
      createPDF( ssID.getId(), s, PDFTitle) ;

    }

  }
}

//    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() ;
//    r = s.getActiveCell() ;
//    var PDFTitle = s.getRange( 'V8' ).getValue() ;
//    var EMAIL_BODY = 'Hello!\rPlease see the attached PDF document.';
//    var OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "Submitted Timesheets" ;
//    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//  createPDF( ssID.getId(), s, PDFTitle) ;

/**
 * Creates a PDF for the customer given sheet.
 * @param {string} ssId - Id of the Google Spreadsheet
 * @param {object} sheet - Sheet to be converted as PDF
 * @param {string} pdfName - File name of the PDF being created
 * @return {file object} PDF file as a blob
 */
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName ) {
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 19, lr = 1150;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=7&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

    //console.log(`ssID: ${ssID}\rurl: ${url}`)//

    const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName( pdfName );

    // Gets the folder in Drive where the PDFs are stored.
    const folder = getFolderByName_(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME);
    const pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob) ;
    sheet.getRange( 'V7' ).setValue( pdfFile.getUrl() );
    return pdfFile;

}
```

I've tried adding in and taking away a sleep timer, but I suspect this is a syntax problem or something (I'm not very experienced with google apps script and google sheets). Frankly, I've been banging my head against this all day and I'm stumped. I'd be happy even with being directed to a resource on how to debug this myself.

For reference, here's my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DCoYqgOgtDpv0a8omPduu9P61uac-wbAueuammn9BEQ/edit?usp=sharing

And here's what I ripped apart to make my scripts
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kT3jCJcjQZVr0JQtEev5exCKhc6VqFhD3UKaBBV6Lvo/copy?resourcekey=0-3CcEz63Pa_yYyf216zbcaw#gid=1382003151

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should add a [mcve], including the textual error message, if any. Simple triggers have several limitations, like a maximum execution time of 30 secs; try using installable triggers instead. Please bear in mind that on edit triggers only are triggered by manual edits, in other words, changes done by and script/ or third party app will not fire the trigger.

Comment: @Rubén I guess that your comment is an answer. In the current stage, the simple trigger cannot use UrlFetchApp. So, how about posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm pretty sure that this was already posted as answer.... probably both of us already have posted something that answer this question :D

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for replying. I agree with you. For example, this might be a duplicated question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20457847

Comment: @Tanaike Good finding. The answer explains what causes the problem briefly and mentions using installable triggers as a workaround, as we agree.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for replying. Now, I flagged it as a duplicated question.

Comment: Thanks guys, you were a lot of help! The linked article by @Tanaike was exactly my problem. I'll make sure to parse code down to a minimal reproducible example in the future as well. I very much appreciate it!